# Get DirectoryInfo make error: acces denied C:\Documents and Settings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I run the code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y798
I have the error : "Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied." 
I try change app.manifest and use try catch but nothing works.

I run it from administrator account. From Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are running under an account that does not allow access to that folder, try changing the path to one that you do have permission to access and trying again or change to an account that does have permission.

**Edit:** Ok I see you're running Windows 7, which doesn't have a 'C:\Documents and Settings' folder by default, it's changed to 'C:\Users'.  If you say you've tried 'C:\' too and it doesn't work, are you sure you're running Visual Studio as an Administrator as by default I don't think it does? (To do this right click on a Visual Studio shortcut and click 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: I changed to c:\ but it always make error. I run it from administrator account. I have to scan whole c:\ because I make file explorer

Comment: I run it "as administrator" but still the same. I add: if (subDir.FullName != "C:\\Documents and Settings" ), but thats show C:\ProgramData\Application Data\' is denied.

Comment: Ok sounds like a folder permission problem, try taking ownership of the folder and see if that fixes it. See this link: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;308421&sd=tech

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're not the computer's administrator. Only an Admin has permission across the whole computer.

You also need to use try-catch every time you try to access the DirecrotyInfo for things like this.

Comment: In particular, you want to catch UnauthorizedAccessException.